# Cómo hacer grids en Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-design

material-ui no tiene el componente para hacer grids como en bootstrap

cómo podría conseguirlo?
o qué otro framework para la UI de react puedo mezclar con material-ui?

Comment: Hola Oscar, recuera que este sitio no es un sustituto de Google. Qué has investigado, probado, intentado antes de preguntar?  Un saludo

Comment: A qué te refieres con que no tienen un componente para grids? El layout de 12 columnas? Porque Materialize sí lo tiene.

Comment: Hola @lois6b he tratado de usar el grid del mismo material-ui pero no es lo mismo que los grids de columnas responsivas como las de bootstrap

el grid de material-ui es más pensado para acomodar fotos o hacer una especie de cuadrícula http://puu.sh/uXoIy/94b5273058.jpg

también intente instalar ambos frameworks material-ui y bootstrap, pero se cruzan en varios estilos no es recomendable

amenadiel materialize es otro framework y no es compatible tampoco no puedo usar ambos a la vez :(